# Scroll According to Mouse Position --jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to scroll the page according to mouse position any idea how to do this using jquery??
To add i have the co-ordinates of mouse.

Adding the actual function . Can you help me out with the scrolling.

```
function createDraggables(){
        $j( ".card" ).draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            containment: "#cardwall",
            drag: function(event,ui) {
                    var viewportHeight = $j(window).height();
                    var documentHeight = $j(document).height();
                    var y = event.pageY - $j('html, body').scrollTop();
                    console.log('==>',this);
                    $j('html, body').scrollTop ( (y / viewportHeight) * documentHeight );
                }
        });
    }
```

Comment: left-right?... top-bottom...? Any code? WHYTSF (What have you tried so far?)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Vanga Sasidhar has what you're looking for. However as you said you have the coordinates you could use this which will smoothly scroll to a given position from the top.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 200 // Replace this value with your coordinates
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do this, based on current mouse position.

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
var documentHeight = $(document).height();

//Lets listen for mousemove event on body tag
$('body').mousemove ( function(e) {
    //Get current y position
    var y = e.pageY - $(this).scrollTop();

    //Based on current proportion, update the document's scrollTop.
    $(this).scrollTop ( (y / viewportHeight) * documentHeight );
});​
```

Working demo can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/GfX3L/

Comment: Well am unable to replicate the above code in this function. Can you help me out?